# polymer 3 create element runtime and inject html inside slot

Tags: polymer, slot

> I am trying to create a polymer element in runtime and injecting HTML
>   inside of it
>
> ```
> here is my code:
> model-dialog.html
> ```

```
class ModelDialog extends PolymerElement {
  static get template() {
    return html`
     <paper-dialog class="size-position" id="modelDialogId" entry-animation="slide-from-right-animation" exit-animation="slide-right-animation" with-backdrop="{{backdrop}}">
      <slot></slot>
     <paper-dialog>
    `;
  }
  static get properties() {
    return {
      header: {
        type: String,
        value: '',
      },

      backdrop:{
        type: Boolean,
        value: false
      }
    };
  }
  showModel()
  {
    this.$.modelDialogId.open();
  }
}

customElements.define('model-dialog', ModelDialog);
```

> In the index.html 
>       i am trying to create this element at runtime and trying to append the content to slot

```
<dom-bind>
    <template is="dom-bind">
      <h3>Basic model-dialog demo</h3>
          <button on-click="_onPrevClick">show model</button>
    </template>
  </dom-bind>
  <script type="module">

    domBind._onPrevClick = function()
    {
 var model1 = document.createElement('model-dialog');
    model1.innerHTML = ` <h2>Dialog Title</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
      aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      Duis aute
      irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
      cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>`;
model1.showModel();
    }
  </script>
```

It is not rendering the HTML in the paper-dialog element which I had created 
actually, the HTML need to render inside slot element which I created inside paper-dialog

Maybe I missed something, or I did it in the wrong way?

kindly help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Where do expect your element to show if you just created it as a JS object, but it's not added anywhere into the page?

Comment: @mishu i am rendering it in the body I forget to add that code